# Ant concat task complain on missing files

Tags: ant, concatenation

```
<concat destfile="dist/external.js">
  <fileset dir=".">
    <include name="a.js" />
    <include name="b.js" />
  </fileset>
</concat>
```

This won't fail if a or b is missing.  I've tried setting optional="false" or asis="true" and it always complains that those attributes don't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to see a warning from the 'concat' task when a file is missing, you can use a[`filelist`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/filelist.html)[resource collection](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/resources.html#collection) in place of the 'fileset':

```
<concat destfile="dist/external.js">
  <filelist dir=".">
    <file name="a.js" />
    <file name="b.js" />
  </filelist>
</concat>
```

When`b.js`doesn't exist, that gives the message:

```
[concat] /Path/.../b.js does not exist.
```

But proceeds anyway, which is probably not what you want.

One method of checking for the presence of all the files in a resource collection is as follows. Note that you need to add the "antlib:org.apache.tools.ant.types.resources.selectors" namespace to the project to use the [resource selectors](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/resources.html#restrict) shown below. (*This won't work for Ant versions older than 1.7.0.*)  Use the Ant [fail task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/fail.html) to check that no resources are missing.

```
<project name="stack_overflow"
         xmlns:rsel="antlib:org.apache.tools.ant.types.resources.selectors">

<filelist id="my.js.files" dir=".">
    <file name="a.js" />
    <file name="b.js" />
</filelist>

<restrict id="missing.js.files">
  <filelist refid="my.js.files"/>
  <rsel:not>
    <rsel:exists/>
  </rsel:not>
</restrict>

<property name="missing.files" refid="missing.js.files" />
<fail message="These files are missing: ${missing.files}">
  <condition>
    <length string="${missing.files}" when="greater" length="0" />
  </condition>
</fail>
<concat destfile="dist/external.js">
    <filelist refid="my.js.files" />
</concat>

</project>
```

When run, as before with`b.js`missing, this fails the build before the 'concat' task with:

```
BUILD FAILED
/Path/.../build.xml:17: These files are missing: /Path/.../b.js
```

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to ding this as correct, I had found this on my own and totally forgot about the question!  It seems fileset and filelist are very different things, I believe fileset performs better because it just hits file in whatever order whether or not they exist.  Filelist looks for each file and fails if any don't exist.